# Prove or disprove that $M = \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : \cos(x)^2 + \exp(z) < \log(1 + z^2 + \sqrt{|xy|})\}$ is open in $ (\mathbb{R}^3)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

I assume that the statement is correct but I struggle how to continue the proof or is there an easier way to prove it?

$M = {(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : cos(x)^2 + exp(z) <log(1 + z^2 + \sqrt{|xy|})\} $ (\mathbb{R}^3)$

To show that (M) is open, we will use the definition of openness in metric spaces.

$A$ set $(A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3)$ is open if for every point $(a \in A)$, there exists an $(\varepsilon > 0)$ such that the open ball $(B(a, \varepsilon) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^3 : ||x - a|| < \varepsilon\})$ is completely contained in $(A)$.

Let $((x_0, y_0, z_0))$ be an arbitrary element of $(M)$. We need to show that there exists an $(\varepsilon > 0)$ such that the open ball $(B((x_0, y_0, z_0), \varepsilon))$ is completely contained in $(M)$.

Consider the function $(f(x, y, z) = \cos(x)^2 + \exp(z) - \log(1 + z^2 + \sqrt{|xy|}))$. This function is continuous since the cosine function, the exponential function, and the logarithm are continuous. Therefore, $(f)$ is continuous on $(\mathbb{R}^3)$.

We observe that $(f(x_0, y_0, z_0) = \cos(x_0)^2 + \exp(z_0) - \log(1 + z_0^2 + \sqrt{|x_0y_0|}) < 0\)$ since $((x_0, y_0, z_0) \in M)$.

By the Intermediate Value Theorem, there exists a $(\varepsilon > 0)$ such that (f(x, y, z) < 0) for all $((x, y, z)\)$ in the open ball $(B((x_0, y_0, z_0), \varepsilon)\)$.

Comment: Hint: if $h:E\to\Bbb R$ is continuous and $U\subset\Bbb R$ is open, then $h^{-1}(U)\subset E$ is open. (Apply this to $E=\Bbb R^3$.)

Comment: The intermediate value theorem is off topic.

Comment: could you eventually give me a bit more detailed hint? I still don't know how to apply your hint with the problem

Comment: My $h$ is your $f$ and $U=(-\infty,0).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $f(x,y,z):=\cos^2x+e^z-\log(1+z^2+\sqrt{|xy|}),$ which is a continuous function from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Now consider $\mathbb{R}_-:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:x<0\}=(-\infty,0)$, which is clearly an open subset. Now we now that preimages of open sets by continupus functions are open, so $f^{-1}((-\infty,0))\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is open, and $M=f^{-1}((-\infty,0))$.